# How to get the selected column in ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid

With ng-grid it is very easy to get the selected row but I cannot discover how to get the selected column. I know you set the option enableCellSelection but what then? What do you do in afterSelectionChange?

Answer (score 0):

Well, got something to work. In case anyone looks here, this is what I did.

First, no enableRowSelection, no enableCellSelection, no afterSelectionChanged. Did the whole thing with just cellTemplate:

```
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ' +
            'ng-click="selectedColumn(row.getProperty(\'employee_id\'), col.index);">' +
            '{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}' +
            '</div>'
```

Then you just need the selectedColumn function:

```
    $scope.selectedColumn = function(id, col) {
        alert(id + "/" + col);
    };
```